# What is await doing here?

Tags: c#, async-await

Given the method signature:

```
(awaitable) Task<Token> ITokenService.GetAPIToken();
```

In this method what is happening on the line with the `await`?

```
public async Task<User> GetUser(string userId)
{
    Token token = await TokenService.GetAPIToken();

    //..........
}
```

My understanding: `GetAPIToken` is called and the current method (`GetUser`) returns a `Task<User>` object (which *will* provide a `User` object later). The current method's execution continues only once the `GetAPIToken` method returns.

If I am wrong, what is the type/value of `token` while the code waits for the `GetAPIToken()` method to return?

I understand that the result of calling this method will be different given that it can be called either with or without the `await` keyword. Please assume, for the post, that it is being called with `await`.

Comment: You are correct. The `GetUsed` method returns at that point, and it will be resumed when the `Task` returned from `GetAPIToken` completes. `token` is not initialized until that `await` completes. It doesn't matter, because you can't access its value until the `await` completes anyway.

Comment: Well, you could [read](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) about it in number of sources.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How and when to use ‘async’ and ‘await’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14455293/how-and-when-to-use-async-and-await)

Comment: I understand that this appears to be a duplicate, but IMHO I am asking about a specific piece of code. Unless those other posts are exactly the same as mine, they don't answer my question. Having said that, they are very close and help me out - though, again, I'm asking about /this/ code because those other posts did not take me all the way (I've seen them before.)

Comment: Your question is not clear. If you await `GetUser` method then you get back `User` and if you don't await it then you get back `Task<User>` which might be already completed and it might not. Then you ask about `token`, so now I'm not sure if you want to know what happens to `GetUser` or `GetAPIToken`...

Comment: I have added clarity. Thank you for the clarification on which type is returned. I'm really asking about the overall execution in the typical scenario.

Comment: @Matt I have completed and corrected my answer; I hope it's clearer now. Eric also explains it perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the line with the `await`, indeed the execution of `GetUser()` is stopped (awaits) until `GetAPIToken()` returns. This is correct. Therefore `token` has no value (or is even declared in this case) until it gets it from `GetAPIToken()` returning.

What `GetUser()` returns depends on how it's called, with or without the `await` operator. If called with `await`, the caller of `GetUser()` will wait for it to finish as well. Also in this case the caller will eventually get a `User` returned by `GetUser()`, not a `Task<User>`.

In this scenario, you're not benefiting by running anything in parallel.

If on the other hand `GetUser()` is called without the `await` operator, two things happen differently: `GetUser()` returns to the caller earlier, as soon as it has hit your line actually; and it returns a `Task<User>` instead of a `User` directly -- after all none had yet been created.

From this `Task` the caller can later (after doing other things in parallel, that'd be the whole point) get the resulting `User`. This can be done in different ways -- the most idiomatic being to `await` it then; or else see the methods and properties of `Task<>`.

It is important to understand when things run in parallel. In that case (if `GetUser()` were called without `await`) it's a possibility that `GetUser()` returns and you continue doing stuff while, in parallel in the other thread, `GetAPIToken()` hasn't yet returned and so `token` is not initialized.

Check this nice MSDN article with graph:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/index#BKMK_WhatHappensUnderstandinganAsyncMethod

Comment: Indeed... but the code doing that is ellipsed as "..." in the question.

Comment: No, the compiler does it because the method is marked as `async`

Comment: What do you mean by "*its async possibly isn't used*" ? The `await` keyword does not negate any asynchronous operation.

Comment: The Task is constructed long before the User object

Comment: @Canton7 indeed; but in the question "later" seem to refer to when GetUser "returns"

Answer (score 7):

> My understanding: `GetAPIToken` is called and the current method (`GetUser`) returns a `Task<User>` object (which will provide a User object later). The current method's execution continues only once the `GetAPIToken` method returns.

That is very close. Let's crisp that up in two ways.

First, let's make a distinction between *returns* -- which means, returns control to the caller -- and *completes*, which means the task represented by the method is completed and either we have its value, or, in the case of abnormal completion, an exception.

In non-async methods we do not need to make a distinction because returning control to the caller only happens on completion. In async methods, we can return-to-caller-as-suspension (because of awaiting a non-completed task) or return-as-completion (when the represented task is signalled as being complete).

Second, it is helpful to express the workflow in terms of what happens if the task is complete when it is created; this can happen in the case of caching, say.

So let's now re-state your understanding with that in mind:

- `GetAPIToken` is called and returns a task to the current user.
- If the task is completed, then GetApiToken returned when it finished all its work. GetUser extracts the token from the completed task and continues without suspending.
- If the task is not completed, and this is the first await in GetUser, then GetUser creates a `Task<User>`
- `GetUser` assigns the remainder of `GetUser` as the continuation of the `Task<Token>`, and suspends by returning the `Task<User>`
- When the `Task<Token>` completes it runs its continuation, which resumes `GetUser` where it left off.

> what is the type/value of token while the code waits for the GetAPIToken() method to return?

Well, what would the value of `token` be in an equivalent non-async case? Consider:

```
Token x = Foo();
```

What's the value of x while we're waiting for Foo to complete? Making Foo async doesn't make a difference; the local is not assigned a value until after the call *completes normally*.  If Foo goes into an infinite loop, or if Foo throws, then `x` is never assigned.

In practice of course, C# assigns all locals their default value when they are created, so that's the value that will be in the variable.